# Como concatenar dois arrays de byte em Java?

Tags: java, array, byte, concatenação-de-string

Eu tenho:

```
byte mensagem[];
byte nonce[];
```

Como faço para concatenar o array `nonce` no final do array `mensagem` e armazenar em um terceiro array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer isto é armazená-los num [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html):

```
byte[] primeiroArray = "stack".getBytes();
byte[] segundoArray  = "overflow".getBytes();
ByteArrayOutputStream terceiroArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

terceiroArray.write(primeiroArray);
terceiroArray.write(segundoArray);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(terceiroArray.toByteArray()));
System.out.println(terceiroArray.toString());

// [115, 116, 97, 99, 107, 111, 118, 101, 114, 102, 108, 111, 119]
// stackoverflow
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/dkc90q)

Uma outra possibilidade é usar a [função `ArrayUtils.addAll()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28T%5B%5D,%20T...%29) da biblioteca *Apache Commons Lang*:

```
byte[] terceiroArray = ArrayUtils.addAll(primeiroArray, segundoArray);
```

Comment: `stack overflow`. Belo exemplo :)

Answer (score 4):

Isto funcionou para mim:

```
byte msg[];
byte nonce[];

byte[] mensagem = new byte[msg.length + nonce.length];
System.arraycopy(msg, 0, mensagem, 0, msg.length);
System.arraycopy(nonce, 0, mensagem, msg.length, nonce.length);
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513152/easy-way-to-concatenate-two-byte-arrays

Answer (score 2):

Tente assim:

```
byte [] terceiro = new byte[mensagem.length + nonce.length];
for (int i = 0; i < terceiro.length; i++) {
    if (i < mensagem.length) {
        terceiro[i] = mensagem[i];
    } else {
        terceiro[i] = nonce[i - mensagem.length];
    }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou, mas tive que fazer algumas modificações. Posso editar sua resposta? Você esqueceu de colocar o `+=` por exemplo.

Comment: Tem um bug neste código. Quando o valor do int é >9 (ou seja, 10) ele dá indexOutBoundsException. Acredito que ele esteja tentando colocar 2 bytes e não cabe.

Comment: @Avelino Na sua sugestão, `nonce[msg.length - i]` não vai dar negativo?

Comment: Então, a primeira solução do Piovezan não funcionou. Fiz algumas modificações, mas só funciona até o 9, passando disto dá erro. Será que era só o += que estava errado? (Deu indexOfBoundsException -1)

Comment: Testei o exemplo e parece ok. E não é necessário `+=` porque não há nenhuma string sendo concatenada, o código trabalha somente com arrays.

Answer (score 2):

```
byte [] terceiro = new byte[mensagem.length + nonce.length];

for (int i = 0; i < mensagem.length; i++) {
    terceiro[i] = mensagem[i];
}
for (int i = mensagem.length; i < terceiro.length; i++) {
    terceiro[i] = nonce[i - mensagem.length];
}
```

Eu declarei o terceiro array com capacidade igual à soma do tamanho dos dois anteriores.

No primeiro loop eu preenchi o terceiro array com os bytes do primeiro array.

No segundo loop eu inicializei um índice para o terceiro array na posição igual ao último índice do primeiro array + 1. E a partir deste índice eu comecei a copiar os ítens do primeiro array.

Comment: Esta solução no final é igual a do @Piovezan mas usa um loop no lugar do IF; para quem, como eu, não goste muito de IFs :-)

Comment: Tá certo, assim fica mais fácil de entender. :)